# Removes certain types from generated WSDL in WCF?

Tags: wcf, wsdl

How can I remove specific types from the the generated WSDL document of a WCF service?

I already have a System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription for my service in a custom IWsdlExportExtension. Where can I find the types in the service description?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating your .NET proxy class using the `svcutil` command line utility, you can define a command-line switch

```
/excludeType:<type>

Specifies a fully-qualified or assembly-qualified type name 
to be excluded from referenced contract types.

When using this switch together with /r from separate DLLs, 
the full name of the XSD class is referenced.

Short Form: /et
```

See the [complete and freely available MSDN documentation for `svcutil`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) for more details.